# Auto- login in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5

I've used **NSUser Defaults** in my app and generally it **stores** the user data while signing up and **deletes** those data while logging out. So, when the user signsup and then logs in, the stored data in NSUser Defaults makes the **auto login** part effective, even when the user closes the app and re opens it again.

But the problem is, when the user logs out, its asking him to signup again. What i want is that, if the user signsup, that information should be **stored permenantly** and when he signs out, it shouldnt ask him to signup again as it should **only clear the memory of the login page** , so that the other user can use the same app.

Iam using **iOS 5**. So, can i use **SQLite** database(to store the signedup info permenantly) and **NSUser Defaults**(to clear the memory of the login page) together in my app? Or is there any alternate solution to this?

Comment: what if user deletes your application? database will also go away. You should show both options, sign-in and signup (when login data is cleared), other wise it will be auto-login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your app is offline and multiple users can **signup** and **login** in the same app (phone), so i think that best approach will be to save the **signup** data in **sqlite** database (you can use **coredata**)
and **login** info in  **NSUserDefaults**. So when user logsout you just clear your NSUserDefaults value only. Also at login time you can check from your databases that user exist or not as all the users data who have signedup is stored in your database. Also if there is a functionality that user can delete his account, than just clear that user entry from the database.
Hope this helps....

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an Auto login System and storing username and password you should be using the Keychain, not NSUSerDefaults

Read [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1) for more details about using the Keychain.

You can also use the keychain to control login sessions, Im not sure but i think even if the user deletes their app, the details stay in the keychain incase they reinstall the app

Comment: But NSUer Defaults seems to be the common methodology for storing username and password for auto login. So, is it possible to use both the SQlite and NSUser defaults in a single app?

Comment: Its possible, but why SQLite instead of CoreData? Why use SQLite instead of Keychain?